# Add jquery action after AJAX request completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm running a AJAX script to load older posts on scroll. This is working, but what I want to achive is to do an img retina replace. This works for non AJAX requests, but when loading the posts with AJAX it is not working.

Below is the jQuery script I'm using to load the AJAX posts.

```
function imagesHD() {
  var imagesHD = $("img[data-1x]");
  if (window.devicePixelRatio === 2) {
    $.each(imagesHD, function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.attr("src", $this.data("2x"));
    });
  } else {
    $.each(imagesHD, function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.attr("src", $this.data("1x"));
    });
  }
}

jQuery(function($){
  var canBeLoaded = true, // this param allows to initiate the AJAX call only if necessary
      bottomOffset = 2000; // the distance (in px) from the page bottom when you want to load more posts
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var data = {
      'action': 'loadmore',
      'query': onlineincasso_loadmore_params.posts,
      'page' : onlineincasso_loadmore_params.current_page
    };
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){
      $.ajax({
        url : onlineincasso_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
        data:data,
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend: function( xhr ){
          // you can also add your own preloader here
          // you see, the AJAX call is in process, we shouldn't run it again until complete
          canBeLoaded = false; 
        },
        success:function(data){
          if( data ) {
            $('.main').find('.content:last-of-type').after( data ); // where to insert posts
            canBeLoaded = true; // the ajax is completed, now we can run it again
            onlineincasso_loadmore_params.current_page++;
          }
        },
        complete:function(xhr) {
          imagesHD();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Do you know how I'm able to get this working? Sorry for my lack of jquery / ajax knowledge :(

Comment: Add an on complete section to your ajax request and put that code in it.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone! Take this. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You would do this in the success callback of the AJAX function, perhaps putting it in a function and calling it on success.

Comment: Ok, I've added a function, changed the code above in my function and called it on complete, but still nothing is happening.

Comment: why don't you call `imagesHD();` on your `success` callback?

Comment: @Hugosama where do I put that code within the success block